# How to animate this transitions?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

My ionic app consists of a number of views and transitions between them is smooth and animated as expected. Nevertheless, due to design reasons, one of the pages has a pseudo-navigation where using two buttons (advance day, and decrease day to show events in a calendar), contents are redrawn on the same view by JS. This redraw has no animation and contents change abruptly. Is there a way to simulate the normal views transitions when re-drawing a view using ionic?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which transitions are you using ? Can you give us examples ?

Comment: Well, between different html pages everything goes as expected (right to left). Problem arises when the HTML file is the same and from JS, different items are shown. Redrawing occurs abruptly and no transitions happen. So I have nothing to show, just to tell you the situation..